# Conditional Formatting problem in Excel 365 online Build 16.0.17002.42302

Tags: conditional-formatting, date-formatting, excel-online

I hope you can help me with my exhasperation.

I have gone round in circles with this, I have a google sheet that works fine but trying to do the same thing in Excel 365 Online simply doesnt seem to work, I know Its probably me doing something wrong but I just cant see it, I have included a screen shot to try amd make things easier to understand I just want to change the cell color based on the date, IE within the last 30 days green, 31 to 60 days yellow and 61 to 90 days red. I cant even get passed doing the last 30 days.
as you can see By the Date in M3 Indeed All the applicable dates.
[Conditional Formatting Scrn Shot][1]

Thanks to all
Regards
Rick
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nKta.png

Comment: Your dates are dd/mm/yyyy (first day, then month), probably Excel expects mm/dd/yyyy. Also for "last 30 days" you need Greater Than, because the date needs to be _after_ today-30.